# Spring MVC JSR validations are not working when using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. Here JSR validations are not working. When I use JSP its showing the JSR validation messages but when I use Thymeleaf validation is not happening. Just for reference I verified in below link https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.pdf 
I have tried many ways but still the problem persists.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kalavakuri</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvcthemeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <!-- JSR 303/349 Validations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSR 303/349 Validations -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

springmvc.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kalavakuri"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:student"/>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/> <!-- Do not use it in production, it causes performance issue -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Controller class:

```
package com.kalavakuri.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.kalavakuri.model.Country;
import com.kalavakuri.model.StudentVO;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("studentVO")
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeController(Model model) {

        StudentVO studentVO = new StudentVO();
        model.addAttribute("studentVO", studentVO);
        prepareCountries(studentVO);

        return "Index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/registerStudent", params= {"save"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginStudent(@Valid @ModelAttribute("studentVO") StudentVO studentVO, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if(!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            StudentVO vo = new StudentVO();
            vo.setStudentId(studentVO.getStudentVOs().size()+1);
            vo.setUserName(studentVO.getUserName());
            vo.setRemember(studentVO.getRemember());
            vo.setPreferredCountry(studentVO.getPreferredCountry());
            vo.setIsHomeCountry(studentVO.getIsHomeCountry());
            studentVO.getStudentVOs().add(vo);
        }

        return "Index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/registerStudent", params= {"removeRow"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String removeStudent(@Valid @ModelAttribute("studentVO") StudentVO studentVO, @RequestParam("removeRow") int studentId) {

        studentVO.getStudentVOs().remove(studentId);
        return "Index";
    }

    /**
     * @param studentVO
     */
    private void prepareCountries(StudentVO studentVO) {
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        Country country1 = new Country();
        country1.setCountryCode("IN");
        country1.setCountryName("India");

        Country country2 = new Country();
        country2.setCountryCode("US");
        country2.setCountryName("United States Of Ameriac");

        countries.add(country1);
        countries.add(country2);

        studentVO.setCountries(countries);
    }
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Student Registration::</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{registerStudent}" th:object="${studentVO}" method="post" id="studentVO">
        <h2 style="padding-left: 750px">Welcome to Spring MVC Thymeleaf</h2>
        <table style="padding-left: 750px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{userName}" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('userName')}? fieldError"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" th:field="*{password}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>You Want Me To Remember:</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{remember}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select Preferred Country:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select th:field="*{preferredCountry}">
                            <option value="Select">Select</option>
                            <option th:each="country: *{countries}" th:value="${country.countryCode}" th:text="${country.countryName}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Is Selected Country, Home Country</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" th:field="*{isHomeCountry}" th:value="Yes"> Yes <input type="radio" th:field="*{isHomeCountry}" th:value="No"> No</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                    <td align="left"><button name="save" type="submit" th:text="Register"></button> &nbsp<input type="reset" th:value="Reset"> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div style="padding-left: 750px;">
            <table border="1" style="border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <th>User Name</th>
                        <th>Want Me To Remember</th>
                        <th>Preferred Country</th>
                        <th>Is Home Country</th>
                        <th>Delete Operation</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="student, rowStat : ${studentVO.studentVOs}">
                        <td th:text="${student.studentId}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${student.userName}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${student.remember}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${student.preferredCountry}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${student.isHomeCountry}"></td>
                        <td><button type="submit" name="removeRow" th:value="${rowStat.index}">Remove row</button> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
package com.kalavakuri.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class StudentVO {

    private long studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private String studentAge;
    @Size(min=3,max=10,message="User name should be minimum 3 characters and maximum 10 characters")
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private Boolean remember;
    private String preferredCountry;
    private List<Country> countries;
    private String isHomeCountry;
    private List<StudentVO> studentVOs = new ArrayList<StudentVO>();

    /**
     * @return the studentId
     */
    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    /**
     * @param studentId the studentId to set
     */
    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the studentName
     */
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    /**
     * @param studentName the studentName to set
     */
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the studentAge
     */
    public String getStudentAge() {
        return studentAge;
    }
    /**
     * @param studentAge the studentAge to set
     */
    public void setStudentAge(String studentAge) {
        this.studentAge = studentAge;
    }
    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    /**
     * @param userName the userName to set
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    /**
     * @return the remember
     */
    public Boolean getRemember() {
        return remember;
    }
    /**
     * @param remember the remember to set
     */
    public void setRemember(Boolean remember) {
        this.remember = remember;
    }
    /**
     * @return the preferredCountry
     */
    public String getPreferredCountry() {
        return preferredCountry;
    }
    /**
     * @param preferredCountry the preferredCountry to set
     */
    public void setPreferredCountry(String preferredCountry) {
        this.preferredCountry = preferredCountry;
    }
    /**
     * @return the countries
     */
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }
    /**
     * @param countries the countries to set
     */
    public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }
    /**
     * @return the isHomeCountry
     */
    public String getIsHomeCountry() {
        return isHomeCountry;
    }
    /**
     * @param isHomeCountry the isHomeCountry to set
     */
    public void setIsHomeCountry(String isHomeCountry) {
        this.isHomeCountry = isHomeCountry;
    }
    /**
     * @return the studentVOs
     */
    public List<StudentVO> getStudentVOs() {
        return studentVOs;
    }
    /**
     * @param studentVOs the studentVOs to set
     */
    public void setStudentVOs(List<StudentVO> studentVOs) {
        this.studentVOs = studentVOs;
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll need to add `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum. Its working